I'm the darkness
I am invisible, yet I make things clear, I can be shallow or deep, bringing distant things near. In silence, I speak, and in stillness, I show, reflecting both light and the darkness below. Without me, you stumble, yet too much and you’re blind, always ahead, but often behind. What am I?

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

Here is my try :

 light

Because:

 I am invisible, yet I make things clear - light makes it possible to see
 I can be shallow or deep - there can be much or little light
 bringing distant things near - stars are very far but their light allow us to see them near
 In silence, I speak - didn t figure it out yet (maybe a reference to light language?)
 in stillness, I show -  again light shows.
 reflecting both light - reflection is ligth that bounces of an object
 and the darkness below.  - darkness is the absence of light
 Without me, you stumble - in darckness you can stumble
 yet too much and you’re blind - too much light can blind you
 always ahead - could be a reference to light at the end of the tunnel (death) or meaning there are always good things waiting
 but often behind - there has been light (good things) happening in your past

As for the title: I'm the darkness

 darkness is the absence of light. the fact that light exist makes darkness exist -> I'm the darkness.


Answer is: Vision.
I hope that answer could help somebody.

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Please [edit] to explain how this answer fits the question. For riddles, normally an answer would explain line-by-line why the answer was correct. For example, why would too much vision make someone blind?

Could it be

 A pair of glasses

I am invisible yet I make things clear

 The lenses in glasses are transparent, and they help visually impaired people see.

I can be shallow or deep, bringing distant things near

 Lenses can be concave or convex, and changing

In silence, I speak, and in stillness, I show, reflecting both light and the darkness below

 Lenses simply reflect light in a special way. I’m not sure about the first part though

Without me, you stumble, yet too much and you’re blind

 You can’t see well without glasses, and too many glasses will also impair your vision.

Always ahead, but often behind

 Your glasses are in front of your head, but sometimes you pull them up so they rest on your head

